# MySQL Cluster data node in memory limits

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

What is the maximum amount of RAM per data node I can allocate to MySQL Cluster "in memory" database?
I found some info about total size can not be more then 3 TB (48 data nodes) or 64 GB allocated RAM per data node.

Comment: nobody? c'mon experts :)